# E-learning plugin for WordPress to embed PowerPoints?

Tags: wordpress, powerpoint

I have some Powerpoint courses that I would like to use on my wordpress site as online courses. I've looked at a few LMS / e-learning plugins...StudyPress looked the best however my PowerPoint becomes a downloadable file - which is obviously not what i want to do.
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: A set of HTML files instead?  There are several programs/add-ins that convert Powerpoint to HTML (though PPT itself no longer will do this).

Comment: Thanks @SteveRindsberg I was originally using Adobe Presenter which did this - converting the PPT to an HTML flash file. Thought of an easier solution below...

Answer (score 0):

Well, after spending hours searching for a solution, testing various plugins: LMS, e-learning and courses, I couldn't find one that did what I wanted.

I have decided to save my PPTs as .MP4s and embed these as it's an easy solution, most LMS plugins have the option to embed videos and most importantly, my content cannot be download!

Comment: You may find other issues with movie files in LMSs.  Among other things, they don't allow users to control the flow of the content as easily; they almost certainly don't allow the LMS to track the user's progress through the content.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the [Embed Any Document](https://wordpress.org/plugins/embed-any-document/) plugin.

Comment: When providing answers please reference what you're referring to.  Also, recommendation solutions are not quality answers as this is technically opinion based.  If the recommended plugin were to be removed years to come your answer doesn't provide resolution to the question.  I would advise spending some time under [answering](http://stackoverflow.com/help/answering)

Comment: I've just found that. While you can disable downloads the native frame has a download link!